# Jquery input changes with select box not firing event?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field which a user can type into. This input also has an ajax request when on keyup.

This input field can also be populated by an onchange event triggered by a select box the only problem being that when the input is populated by the select box onchange the ajax is not triggered for the input field as the user doesn't type it in.

I have also used these on the input field to trigger the ajax and none of them work both ways as in when the user manually types in the input field or uses the select box to populate the input field.

```
.live('change, keyup', function() {

.change(function() {
```

Comment: I don't think you should have a comma to separate event types, just a single space.

Comment: Ye typo my bad, but still it doesn't work?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Element `events` will not be triggered when it is value is updated using javascript. You should call the keyup event from the .change function when you set the value as below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BQmE4/1/)

```
.change(function() {
     //...
    $('.input').val($(this).val()).keyup();
 });
```

Comment: change doesn't work as it states in the jquery manual that change is only triggered when the input field is changed onblur

Answer (score 2):

First, attach the keyup handler to the input field, then when clicking your select box you would probably populate your input with something like:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('input').val('some value').keyup();  //the last keyup will trigger the bound keyup on the input
});
```

This will trigger the keyup, wich in turn will run your ajax function!

EDIT:
And I see now that this is pretty much the answer SKS has given, and it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `onfocus` JS / [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) JQuery

Comment: this doesn't work as the input is never in focus when the user changes the select box